# 'New' Object won't specify while creating an object inside the class

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to create a class that will hold the object for the XML file. But it won't create a 'New' object. Here's my sample code below:

```vb
    Private Sub CreateXml()
        New XmlConfigSource().Save("myConfig.xml") 'this is the error.
    End Sub
```

What will I do in order to make this code work? Thank you for answering. :)

Comment: You'll need to declare your object first. Dim xmlObj as <yourtype> ..

Comment: What is the error?  You can try enclosing the construction of the object in parentheses:  `(New XmlConfigSource()).Save("myConfig.xml")`

Comment: It won't hold anything, because once it is used it will be garbage collected. There is no lasting reference to the object. If you just want a class which can perform functions for you but not save any state, use a static class (`Module` in VB.Net, like `static class` in C#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot begin a line of code with the `New` keyword.  It's actually the only situation I've found the `Call` keyword to be genuinely useful.  This will compile and do as you intend:

```vb
Private Sub CreateXml()
    Call New XmlConfigSource().Save("myConfig.xml")
End Sub
```

Comment: You would need parentheses. `Call (New XmlConfigSource()).Save("myConfig.xml")`

Comment: @djv, no, you don't need parentheses. Test it for yourself. The compiler is clearly smart enough to know that there's only one way to interpret that expression and so does so. You do need to include the parentheses on the constructor call itself though, i.e. after the type. I usually don't include those parentheses on a constructor but they are required in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers guys. But I found some alternatives. This is what I'm doing:

```
    Private Sub CreateXml()
        Dim xmlConfig As String = "myConfig.xml"
        Dim XML As XmlConfigSource = New XmlConfigSource()
        XML.Save(xmlConfig)
    End Sub
```

I hope this satisfies you all. Thank you for sharing some thoughts. :)

Comment: It seems like you only need a static class, because your `New XmlConfigSource` isn't reused.